# Determine if DataTables is done in version 1.10. Is there a callback?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, datatables-1.10

How can I determine if DataTables() is done rendering in version 1.10 and above? Is there a callback somewhere I can set to a function. I'd like to hide my table until DataTables is finished and then reveal it once it is done loading.

With version 1.10, I haven't come across a callback, and I think a lot of the old callbacks are now deprecated as their links redirect me to legacy.datatables.net

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`init.dt`](http://datatables.net/reference/event/init) event as follows:

```
$('#example').on('init.dt', function(e, settings, json){
    console.log( 'Table initialisation complete: '+new Date().getTime() );
});

$('#example').dataTable();
```

From the [manual](http://datatables.net/reference/event/init):

> `init` event is called when your table has fully been initialised, data loaded and drawn, particularly when using an `ajax` data source.

**NOTES**

If you're going to hide/show the table, you would need to use [`columns.adjust()`](http://datatables.net/reference/api/columns.adjust%28%29) API method to recalculate column widths once table becomes visible.

For example:

```
$('#example-container').hide();

$('#example').on('init.dt', function(e, settings, json){
    $('#example-container').show();

    $(this).DataTable().columns.adjust();
});

$('#example').dataTable();
```